# Type arguments error in LINQ extension method

Tags: linq, entity-framework, arguments

I wrote a LINQ extension to join 2 tables

```
public static IEnumerable<ObjectDetail<TLeft, string>> ToDetail<TLeft, TRight, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TLeft> left, IEnumerable<TRight> right, Func<TLeft, TKey> leftProperty, Func<TRight, TKey> rightProperty, Func<TRight, TKey> keyProperty, Func<TRight, TKey> valueProperty, string keySelector)
        {
            return (from l in left
                    join r in right on leftProperty(l) equals rightProperty(r) into one
                    select new
                    {
                        l,
                        one
                    }).AsEnumerable().Select(q => new ObjectDetail<TLeft, string>
                    {
                        Item = q.l,
                        Meta = q.one.Where(m => keySelector.Contains(keyProperty(m).ToString())).ToDictionary(m => keyProperty(m).ToString(), m => valueProperty(m).ToString())
                    });
        }
```

The compiler understand the extension well but when I try to write

```
var result = left.ToDetail(right, l => l.ID, r => r.ID, r => r.Key, r => r.Value, "Key");
```

I got the following error:

> The type arguments for method
>   .ToDetail(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable,
>   System.Func,
>   System.Func,
>   System.Func,
>   System.Func, string)'
>   cannot be inferred from the usage. Try
>   specifying the type arguments
>   explicitly

Then I tried to remove the keyProperty and valueProperty parameters from the extension, it run well without any error. I don't know why, maybe the compiler confused and cannot determine the parameter with the same type?

Any helps would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you post the declarations of the types involved? Perhaps `right`'s source-type's `Key` and `Value` properties are of different types? Or maybe the `ID` s are of different-types? Either of these would cause type-inference errors that are probably real logic-errors.

Comment: Key and Value properties are the same type. They are all string. ID of left and right are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function declaration, you use the same function type for `rightProperty`, `keyProperty` and `valueProperty` arguments, so both of these functions should have a type `Func<TRight, TKey>`.

This means that when you call the function, the type of `r.ID`, `r.Key` and `r.Value` must be the same (so that the C# compiler can infer the `TKey` type parameter from these two). My guess is that in your example, at least one of these three is different (probably `ID`).

(Aside, since you're converting the result of `valueSelector` and `keySelector` to string using the `ToString` method, there is probably no reason why you need to use generic types - a function returning `object` should do the trick).

Comment: Thanks for your explaination! It helps me a lot.